# Example expression with four comparison operators

Tags: operators, expression, grammar

I'm trying to write the simplest valid expression for the following 4 comparison operators, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`. My thinking was:

```
(1 < 2) <= (3 > 2)
```

And I've got three...What would be a simple expression with all four?

---

Here's an example that uses one operator twice:

```
(1 < 2) <= (3 > 2) >= (1 < 2)
```

Or, if we allow a boolean literal:

```
(1 < 2) <= (3 > 2) >= true
```

Comment: "Valid" in what sense? Syntactically correct? Meaningful? Not redundant? Also, what language are you talking about? Not all languages allow ordered comparisons between boolean values (although FALSE < TRUE is probably more common).

Comment: Well, "valid" in that only same-types can be compared (in this case an `int` or `bool`). So, for example `false < 1` wouldn't be allowed or valid. For argument's sake, let's assume `false < true` in this grammar.

Comment: @rici not sure if my example makes sense but I updated the question.